# Multithreaded server - multiple clients, one server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client, server

Ok so IVe found alot of similar questions on here about this but I still dont really understand what exactly to do. Im trying to allow multiple clients connect to a single server that sends screenshots to every client connected.

SO I have three class for this screen sharing/broadcasting software :

1. server class that contains the code to create a GUI, a ServerSocket and a Socket(outToClient) for the client. A thread of the screenshot class below is created when a button is clicked on the GUI, this does all the work of taking and sending screenshots.

   ```
   Thread t1 = new Thread(new screenshot());
   t1.start();
   ```
2. a screenshot class that takes screenshots converts the images to byte arrays and sends it to the client through the Socket in the server class:

   ```
    server.outToClient.writeObject(imageInByte);
   ```
3. a client class that receives the byte arrays, converts the byte arrays to buffered images and displays them in a JFrame in a GUI.

Now from what ive been reading I should create a Handler class, and the server class should spawn a thread of the Handler class for each client that tries to connect that handles the clients.

My question is what code do I put in the Handler class from the server class or the client class and do I have to change what the server class and client class does?Should I be creating the thread for the screenshot in the Handler class etc?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The reason why people use Handler threads is simple: a server cannot waste its time for handling each client request by itself. That is why the server delegates this job to a handler. The Handler should read all bytes sent by a client and forward them to all clients through their sockets. Be careful to use these client sockets in a synchronized way.

Comment: If you did not use a Handler, your server would not be able to process all client calls fast enough.

Comment: Hi vojta - " The Handler should read all bytes sent by a client" , the clients dont sent any bytes, they just receive bytes. Did you mean all bytes sent by the server?

Comment: I thought that client sends a screenshot and server distributes it to all other clients via its handlers. Am I right? So your handler should read the screenshot sent by the sending client and forward it.

Comment: No in my server class I instantiate an ObjectOutputStream: 

public static ObjectOutputStream outToClient = ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

The screenshot class takes screenshots and sends them through this ObjectOutputStream - server.outToClient.writeObject(imageInByte);

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. So your handlers should only register your clients = add their objectOutputStream to some synchronized collection.